# how to use session in woocommerce pages like we use normal php session?

Tags: woocommerce

How can i store my data in woocommerce session and used it anywhere in woocommerce pages(like thankyou page,processing mail page). 2nd i just have to send a unique code in woocommerce email(both admin and user). How to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24):

For using session you can do

```
// Test if your are on Back Office, WC()->session isn't set
if( !is_admin() ){
    $data = 'test';
    WC()->session->set( 'name_for_your_data' , $data );

    $retrive_data = WC()->session->get( 'name_for_your_data' );
}
```

Comment: How could one reset their session after mucking around with it?

Comment: Caveat: WooCommerce session can only be reliably used for variable storage after cart is created. See https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/4920

Comment: How can I check if the session isn't empty though?