# avoid a script being loaded on a browser refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, browser, woocommerce

I have a conversion code to be run in the browser after a purchase in a WooCommerce shop. That code has to be run only once. A reload of the thankyou page would cause the conversion to be counted twice instead of once.

I've googled a few solutions but I'm not sure what the right strategy would be, meaning the strategy with the most accurate results.

Set a server hash variable after the first load and prevent a reload of the script if the variable is set?
Cookies?
Ajax?

What is the most promising strategy to achieve an accurate solution?

Comment: Maybe you should account for that in your reporting somehow? Maybe better if you look at the fact that the same event was sent multiple times. Maybe have some kinda session variable sent with each event in so you know how many times that session sent that event? If that's even possible?

Comment: no. unfortunately I have no control over that.

Comment: What conversion code are you using, Google AdWords Conversion?

Comment: hi slapyo. yes Google AdWords

Answer (score 2):

After running your script, do a redirect with [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to a different page. This is quite common on pages that accept POST forms, to redirect after processing so the user can't resubmit.

```
header("Location: http://the.other.url/");
```

Comment: I like the idea, but it would mean I have to change the normal functioning of WooCommerce which is out of question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently WooCommerce supports sessions: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html

I believe with this solution it can be done nicely: [how to use session in woocommerce pages like we use normal php session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199656/how-to-use-session-in-woocommerce-pages-like-we-use-normal-php-session)